Realm Join Linux - can't login with AD user
I have added my Red Hat Linux 9 to the Active Directory with realm. I see the computer in AD now.
Then I did realm permit --all
In /etc/ssh/sshd_config I added :
# Authentication:
AllowGroups "Domain Admins"

My account is in the Domain Admins group.
File /etc/sssd/sssd.conf:
[sssd]
domains = example.corp
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/example.corp]
dyndns_update = false
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = EXAMPLE.CORP
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
id_provider = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
ad_domain = example.corp
ad_hostname = DC01.example.corp
use_fully_qualified_names = True
ldap_id_mapping = True
access_provider = ad

Login fails:
> ssh -l jsmith@example.corp 10.120.10.106
jsmith@example.corp@10.120.10.106's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
jsmith@example.corp@10.120.10.106's password:

And the messages log has the following
Nov 20 14:28:32 MYLINUX krb5_child[918103]: Pre-authentication failed: Invalid argument
Nov 20 14:28:32 MYLINUX krb5_child[918104]: Preauthentication failed
Nov 20 14:28:32 MYLINUX krb5_child[918104]: Preauthentication failed
Nov 20 14:28:32 MYLINUX krb5_child[918104]: Preauthentication failed


Kerberos is a finicky beast. Your messages log shows the machine name as MYLINUX but the sssd.conf shows it as DC01. This may matter, particularly as the manpage for sssd-ad warns about mismatches (my emphasis):

ad_hostname (string) Optional. May be set on machines where the hostname(5) does not reflect the fully qualified name used in the Active Directory domain to identify this host.
This field is used to determine the host principal in use in the keytab. It must match the hostname for which the keytab was issued.


I removed "AllowGroups "Domain Admins" from the sshd.config, rebooted and now it works.
Go figure.
thanks

I'd try either "domain admins"@example.corp or "domain/domain admins" or possibly"domain\\domain admins" (but this last one is least likely, and you might also want to try just a single backslash instead of the pair)
